# can't select data from a dictionary inside a list

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have two jsonb fields in the table below and I would like to do a query where I filter any key of the dictionary.

[image: Table with data]

My problem is that those dictionaries are inside of a list and when I try to access them with:

```
SELECT *
FROM public.monitoring_environmentalcontrol
WHERE celery_status->'queue'='0'
```

I get nothing:

[image: Result table]

Comment: Hi there, can you please add sample data instead of just images of your question? That would help us to create a testing environment so we can provide you with an answer. Here are some tips on how you can improve your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557

Comment: Sure, first time asking for help about an issue like this one so I didn't know how to better do it

Comment: No worries, we are here to help each other always :)

Comment: Hi there Pedro, did the answer helped you? if so, please consider in accepting it. You do so by clicking in the V icon in the left side of the answer.

Comment: The answer did help me, thanks a lot. Was away because of the weekend. I could only answer it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements` [DOC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) function to achieve your goal plus a `LATERAL JOIN` [7.2.1.5. LATERAL Subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html) on it:

This is the setup I created:

```
create table test (
  id int, 
  celery_status jsonb
);

insert into test values 
(1,'[{"queue":"a"}, {"queue":"b"}, {"queue":"c"}]'),
(2,'[{"queue":"d"}, {"queue":"e"}, {"queue":"f"}]'),
(3,'[{"queue":"g"}, {"queue":"h"}, {"queue":"i"}]');
```

This is the query:

```
select t.id, t.celery_status, obj->>'queue'
from test t
     join lateral
     jsonb_array_elements(t.celery_status) obj(value) on obj->>'queue' = 'a'
```

You can see it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bf7bf/6